# Setting up Nested Resource Routes in Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel, routes, controllers

I'm setting up nested resource routes in my application. Currently, I have

```
// in app/routes
Route::resource("users.folders", "FolderController");

// in app/controllers/api/v2
class FolderController extends \BaseController {

    public function index($userId)
    {
        return Response::json( Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($userId)->folders()->with("resources")->get() );
    }

    public function show($userId, $id)
    {
        if( $f = Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($userId)->folders()->with("resources")->find($id) )
        {
            return Response::json( $f );
        }

        return Response::json(["status" => "Not Found"], 404);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm always going to load the user in the same way, but it seems so redundant to always write `Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($userId)`. Is there some way that I can load the correct User in the `__construct` function?

I would love to do something like

```
class FolderController extends \BaseController {

    public function __construct( $userId )
    {
        $this->user = Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($userId);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return Response::json( $this->user->folders()->with("resources")->get() );
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        if( $f = $this->user->folders()->with("resources")->find($id) )
        {
            return Response::json( $f );
        }

        return Response::json(["status" => "Not Found"], 404);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But that causes an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible but you can move this code to function:

```
private function getUsers($id) {
   return Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($userId);
}
```

and now in functions you can use:

```
return Response::json( $this->getUsers($userId)->folders()->with("resources")->get() );
```